# Django 1.9, how to POST multiple select value from html

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

UPDATE:
I found an answer. Just added this little code at the bottom:

```
    $('#myform').submit(function()
{
     $('#dates option').prop('selected', true);
});
```

---

I have a tempate:

```
div class="panel">
                    <div class="large-12 columns">
                      <div class="row collapse">
                        <div class="small-10 columns">
                          <input class="input-append date fdatepicker" id="date" type="text" name="date" value="" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
                        </div>
                        <div class="small-2 columns">
                          <input type="button" name="add" id="btn_AddToList" value="dodaj" class="button postfix" />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <select multiple="multiple" size="10" style="height: auto; width: auto" name="dates" id="dates" tabindex="2">

                    </select>
                </div>
```

and I add dates to #dates select using this little code:

```
   $('#btn_AddToList').click(function () {
    var val = $('#date').val();
    $('#dates').append('<option value="'+val+'">' + val + '</option>');
    $('#date').val('');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
```

})

in my view i want to read dates so i thought i would use:

```
for d in request.POST.getlist('dates'):
                if d is not None:
                    print(d)
```

But I get `None`. I tried to use `request.POST.getlist('dates[]'):` `request.POST.get('dates'):` but with no success. I am recieving `None` all the time.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: print request.POST to check what is coming in post request....

Comment: request.POST.getlist is designed to return a list. If it is returning None than there is some problem with your request. (maybe it's GET and not POST?)

Comment: If you want to know name of method you should use print(request.method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: I found an answer. Just added this little code at the bottom:

```
  $('#myform').submit(function()
{
     $('#dates option').prop('selected', true);
});
```